# Gitlab Mattermost integration

Tags: gitlab-omnibus, mattermost

I setup gitlab on my local network using omnibus package.

I want to use gitlab with mattermost. How to enable gitlab plugin on mattermost for this situation?

Can you describe it step by step?
Thanks

Setup gitlab using omnibus package

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've checked the official documentation  yet.

Here's a [guide for installing](https://mattermost.gitbook.io/plugin-gitlab/setup/installation) and here's [a guide for configuring](https://mattermost.gitbook.io/plugin-gitlab/setup/configuration).
I hope those help you, since they are pretty much step by step.

Please note that you need to be an admin on the Mattermost server for installing and configuring the GitLab Plugin!